# Mock HttpContext in web api using MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am trying to mock HttpContext for web api controller and using moq and did not get any relevant post regarding web api controller after googling so please help me.

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

            context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Session).Returns(session.Object);
            context.Setup(c => c.Server).Returns(server.Object);


            return context.Object;
```

that way works for MVC but not in web api because we can pass HttpContextBase to ControllerContext in MVC but not in Web API.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Comment: Also stop tightly coupling your code to `HttpContext` It is an implementation concern that is difficult to test. You can avoid that problem by structuring your code properly. Treat `HttpContext` like a 3rd party dependency.

Comment: That means, is there no way to mock httpcontext in web api without passing as external dependency?

Comment: It depends. You need to provide more context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please check now question is clear or not.

Comment: Show what it is you are trying to test. `HttpContext` was abstracted away in Web API 2 because of the same limitation I listed before.

Comment: Again without know how you intend to use it there is not much more help that can be provided until you clarify the question.

Comment: @maheshsharma any idea sir how u achieve this..i am getting the same error and didn't find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do we feel about this?

```
public interface IHttpContext
{
    string Url { get; }
}

public class HttpContextProvider : IHttpContext
{
    public string Url => HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
}

public class MockedHttpContextProvider : IHttpContext
{
    public string Url => "https://google.com";
}
```

I agree you shouldn't pass HttpContext deep into your application, but if you are refactoring old code and it's already been passed a long way down the tree, I find the below is a great way to write unit tests for your new code and not have to touch other peoples stuff!